# Enable Hot Reloading With Webpack and PostCSS

Tags: webpack, webpack-dev-server, postcss, css-modules, extract-text-plugin

I am looking to hot reload my window when I save a stylesheet in my text editor. Currently, I have to manually reload the page to see any changes. Below is the snippet in my Webpack configuration file that handles processing css:

```
module: {
  rules: [
    {
      test: /\.js$/,
      exclude: path.resolve(__dirname, 'node_modules'),
      loader: 'babel-loader',
    },
    {
      test: /\.css$/,
      include: [`${PATHS.src}`, `${PATHS.modules}/normalize.css/normalize.css`],
      use: ExtractTextPlugin.extract({
        fallback: 'style-loader',
        use: [
          {
            loader: 'css-loader',
            options: {
              modules: true,
              localIdentName: '[name]__[local]___[hash:base64:5]',
              importLoaders: 1,
            },
          },
          'postcss-loader',
        ],
      }),
    },
  ],
}
```

I am using Webpack 3, Webpack Dev Server and PostCSS along with the Extract Text Plugin. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To enable hot reloading for css using the `ExtractTextWebpackPlugin`, there are multiple steps you need to follow.

**1. Configure webpack-dev-server**

```
devServer: {
  host: '0.0.0.0',
  port: 8080,
  hot: true
}
```

**2. Add the HotModuleReplacementPlugin**

```
plugins: [
  new webpack.HotModuleReplacementPlugin()
]
```

**3. Add an entrypoint for the dev server**

```
entry: [
  'webpack-dev-server/client?http://0.0.0.0:8080',
  // your other entry points
]
```

**4. Use css-hot-loader**

Please refer to the documentation, since the first example contains `ExtractTextPlugin`. View it [here](https://www.npmjs.com/package/css-hot-loader).

**5. Setup the hot-module script in your .js entrypoint**

Inside your .js entry point, you should implement the following script:

```
if (module.hot) {
  module.hot.accept();
}
```

Those steps should provide you with hot reloading of both JS and CSS.
Let me know, if there are any issues or questions.

Comment: I modified my Webpack configuration file as specified above and I receive an unexpected token error on the closing parenthesis for the concat function used for css-hot-loader as specified by documentation. The specific piece of code causing the error is `['css-hot-loader'].concat(..rest of configuration)`.

Answer (score 0):

You need not use `ExtractTextPlugin` for development of app. Use a loader for css and have a separate config for webpack.prod

Have you included devServer in webpack.config along with module?

```
devServer: {
    hot: true,
    contentBase: ENTRY_DIR
  },
```

And you should run your app with webpack-dev-server.

Comment: I use `ExtractTextPlugin` so the stylesheet is separated from the JS bundle, and I would like to keep it that way so I can modify my CSS in the browser. I'm already using a loader for CSS. I don't have a separate production Webpack configuration file, but I don't think it's necessary for my use case. Lastly, `DevServer` is already in my Webpack configuration file.

Comment: Would seeing the rest of my configuration file be useful?

Comment: @iknowhtml ExtractTextPlugin doesnt support HMR. kapish.